# When should I consider saving the total count in a field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

For example, if I have to count the comments belonging to an article, it's obvious I don't need to cache the comments total.

But what if I want to paginate a gallery (WHERE status = 1) containing 1 million photos. Should I save that in a table called counts or SELECT count(id) as total every time is fine?

Are there other solutions?

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL, you don't need to store the counts, you can use [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to avoid two queries.

E.g.,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM Gallery
WHERE status = 1
LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

From the manual:

> In some cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement
>   would have returned without the LIMIT, but without running the
>   statement again. To obtain this row count, include a
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT statement, and then invoke
>   FOUND_ROWS() afterward.

Sample usage [here](http://tomhenry.us/tbs3/navbar_foundrows/paging_calcfoundrows.php).

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on the amount of queries that are done on that table with 1 million records. Consider just taking care of good indexes, especially also multi-column indexes (because they are easily forgotton: [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) That will do a lot. And, be sure the queries become cached also well on your server.

If you use this column very regular, consider saving it (if it can't be cached by MySQL), as things could become slow. But most of the times good indexing will take care of it.

Best try: setup some tests to find out if a query can still be fast and performance is not dropping when you execute it a lot of times in a row.

```
EXPLAIN [QUERY]
```

Use that command (in MySQL) to get information about the way the query is performed and if it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the count every time would be OK.

During paging, you can use [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) anyway

Note:

1. A denormalied count will become stale
2. No-one will page so many items